# Hiding other elements by one input field

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, hide

Please can you provide me some short help with my Javascript code. I have one input field which hides DIV element just if it is totally empty (without text):

```
if (search_value !== "") {
    document.getElementById("frei").className = "frei1";
    }
```

It does exactly what I want, the main problem is once the input field is activated by typing inside and when I start to erase the text until the input is empty, than my hidden DIV appear, even if the input contain no text (because I erased it). This function is good only on first page load, than when I type anything in input and erase it, my JavaScript code is not functional.

Please could you give me an advice how looks like Javasript code, which hide that DIV everytime input field contain no text? Even when the text was erased manually?

Thank you very much and apologize for that type of question. Iam not strong in basic Javascript.

Comment: Just to be more precise: In CSS ID frei is visible and ID frei1 has display:none;

Comment: onkeyup event you may be needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code will only execute on page load, yet you want it to run each time someone types into your input, to do that you can use the `onkeyup` event:

```
document.getElementById("yourInput").onkeyup = function () {
    if (this.value !== "") {
        document.getElementById("frei").className = "frei1";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("frei").className = "";
    }
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vcg4ymr3/1/)

If you also need it to run on page load aswell however, extract it out to a function and then you can call the function on page load as well:

```
function setDisplay() {
    if (document.getElementById("yourInput").value !== "") {
        document.getElementById("frei").className = "frei1";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("frei").className = "";
    }
}
```

Then call it on page load:

`setDisplay();`

Then also attach it to the `onkeyup` event like we did in the first instance:

```
document.getElementById("yourInput").onkeyup = setDisplay;
```

Comment: can you tell me the value of this here ??..is it window ?? or the value of the clicked elEment ??

Comment: @AvinashBabu `this` in that function refers to the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("id").oninput = function() {
    if (this.value !== "") {
        document.getElementById("frei").className = "frei1";
   }
}
```

or

```
document.getElementById("id").addEventListener('input',function() {
    if (this.value !== "") {
        document.getElementById("frei").className = "frei1";
   }
}, false);
```